# How to install moonlight in Ubuntu 12.0.4?

Tags: silverlight, ubuntu, moonlight

I tried to open the this [link](https://coxy7ezff6.database.windows.net/) in Ubuntu. but it suggested to install silverlight.[image]

I searched in Google for this,finally I got Ubuntu not supported to `SilverLight`.so we need to install `MoonLight`.

for this, I run the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

after installing, I refresh the above page. still it's showing like that.

How can I fix this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well for me I had to install a User Agent plugin for firefox to make netflix, which requires Silverlight, think I was using firefox on a windows system. Here's the one I used:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/user-agent-overrider/?src=search

And this is the setup I used to install pipelight:
http://www.webupd8.org/2013/08/pipelight-use-silverlight-in-your-linux.html

and I enabled it system wide using: 
sudo pipelight-plugin --enable silverlight

I didn't have to do any of the steps after that. So basically all you do is take a screen-shot of the page or write down the steps, close firefox, download and install it using your terminal. Restart firefox back up and then make sure you set your User Agent plugin to windows firefox and then it should work ^-^. I hope this helps.

Ubuntu Studio 13.10 Saucy x64